# dotnet restore cmd failing - error MSB4019 - \DotNet\Microsoft.DotNet.Props file missing #5175

Tags: yeoman, .net-core, yeoman-generator

So I've done some searching most articles suggest installing the Vs2015 tooling. Which I have installed. But I am still getting this error when I try to restore a project from Yeomans. The 'Microsoft.DotNet.Props' file definitely does not exist on my machine. Im running Windows 7 x64 with Vs2015update3 and Vs2015 tools preview 2.0.3. What am I doing wrong?

Not sure if this helps but here is my dotnet --info

Product Information:
Version: 1.0.0-preview4-004233
Commit SHA-1 hash: 8cec61c

Runtime Environment:
OS Name: Windows
OS Version: 6.1.7601
OS Platform: Windows
RID: win7-x64
Base Path: C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\1.0.0-preview4-004233

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to work through this issue.  The original Yeomans template I was using was generated with a different version to dotnet so I had to manually force this switch using the global.json file with Solution file and the Visual Studio IDE was able to update the build.  Then I could switch back and get the builds to run.  This may not be the only way but this did work for me in this case.  Here is more details on the issue.

https://forums.asp.net/t/2113044.aspx?dotnet+restore+failing+error+MSB4019+1+0+0+preview4+004233+Microsoft+VisualStudio+v14+0+DotNet+Microsoft+DotNet+Props+was+not+found+